# Stylecheck: ERROR: space required before the open parenthesis '('

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, lint

I have a C++ macro it looks like below,

```
#define UTRACE_WRITE(trace_fd, ...)     do { if (trace_fd >= 0) this->trace_write (trace_fd, __VA_ARGS__); } while(0);
```

Style check program checkpatch.pl through an error as below

```
ERROR: space required before the open parenthesis '('
```

How to overcome the above error instead of using `/*IGNORE_STYLE_CHECK*/`?

Also, my style check code giving a warning for ';' What is the future problem if I ignore this?

```
WARNING: do {} while (0) macros should not be semicolon terminated
```

Comment: If i specify space as `UTRACE_WRITE (trace_fd, ...)` It will through error as `ERROR: Macros with multiple statements should be enclosed in a do - while loop`

Comment: There must not be a space between the macro name and the left paren. That's just standard C. The error you get is due to `while(0)`. It tells you to write `while (0)`.

Comment: You need a space at the end: `while (0)`. Having the semicolon in the macro can mess up if/else statements `if (x) UTRACE_WRITE(something); else ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I really like answers, so here it is:

```
#define UTRACE_WRITE(trace_fd, ...)     do { if (trace_fd >= 0) this->trace_write (trace_fd, __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)
```

put a space in here in front of the open parenthesis: `while (0)`

and remove the semicolon after the close parenthesis at the end.